# How to combine two lists into dictionary in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to combine the values of two lists into single dictionary set but after combining dictionaries key and values are not arranged as  origional order in list , it pairs with random key and values, so how can I combine them in order? See the input and output below:

```
data_ids = ['22630876', '22626950', '22624826', '22626159', '22616496', '22601480', '22611197', '22600498', '22605808', '22602601', '22602543', '22594071', '22595982', '22593725', '22591441', '22553315', '22584758']



tag_ids = ['WATCH - Stokes faces unpredictable balls', "'Bad position, but we're not out of it' - de Villiers", 'Who is Sandeep Lamichhane?', 'WATCH - All the action from the Super Over', "WATCH - Sammy's four-ball blitz", "Shubman Gill's red-hot run streak", 'Should bowlers start wearing helmets?', 'Keshav Maharaj could be key - Graeme Smith', "WATCH - Kevin Pietersen's match-winning 48", "'It was emotional walking off the pitch' - Stokes", "WATCH - India's gains from the South Africa tour", 'WATCH - Best of Kohli in South Africa', 'The Ashwin-Gibbs exchange: funny, or not?', "Mayank Agarwal's incredible run of domestic form", "'SA can't afford spicy pitches against Australia'", 'Ice Cricket: Legends play T20 in the Alps', 'Dhoni, Kohli and quirky on-field  chatter']


z = dict(zip(data_ids,tag_ids))

print(z)



{'22595982': 'The Ashwin-Gibbs exchange: funny, or not?', '22593725': "Mayank Agarwal's incredible run of domestic form", '22626159': 'WATCH - All the action from the Super Over', '22553315': 'Ice Cricket: Legends play T20 in the Alps', '22626950': "'Bad position, but we're not out of it' - de Villiers", '22624826': 'Who is Sandeep Lamichhane?', '22611197': 'Should bowlers start wearing helmets?', '22630876': 'WATCH - Stokes faces unpredictable balls', '22600498': 'Keshav Maharaj could be key - Graeme Smith', '22602601': "'It was emotional walking off the pitch' - Stokes", '22602543': "WATCH - India's gains from the South Africa tour", '22591441': "'SA can't afford spicy pitches against Australia'", '22601480': "Shubman Gill's red-hot run streak", '22594071': 'WATCH - Best of Kohli in South Africa', '22605808': "WATCH - Kevin Pietersen's match-winning 48", '22584758': 'Dhoni, Kohli and quirky on-field  chatter', '22616496': "WATCH - Sammy's four-ball blitz"}
```

as you can see the output of `z` starts with key value `'22595982'` but it should be `'22630876'`, even same with values of dictionary, how can I do this, I searched for similar question but I didn't find any

Comment: Use Python 3.7.

Comment: doesn't it work with 3.5.2? @wim

Comment: They will be paired up correctly, and that's all that matters.  If you need to preserve original ordering, then you've got the wrong data structure here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I guess this will be your answer.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict(zip(data_ids, tag_ids))
for i, j in d.items():
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

Outputs:

```
22630876
WATCH - Stokes faces unpredictable balls
22626950
'Bad position, but we're not out of it' - de Villiers
22624826
Who is Sandeep Lamichhane?
22626159
WATCH - All the action from the Super Over
22616496
WATCH - Sammy's four-ball blitz
22601480
Shubman Gill's red-hot run streak
22611197
Should bowlers start wearing helmets?
22600498
Keshav Maharaj could be key - Graeme Smith
22605808
WATCH - Kevin Pietersen's match-winning 48
22602601
'It was emotional walking off the pitch' - Stokes
22602543
WATCH - India's gains from the South Africa tour
22594071
WATCH - Best of Kohli in South Africa
22595982
The Ashwin-Gibbs exchange: funny, or not?
22593725
Mayank Agarwal's incredible run of domestic form
22591441
'SA can't afford spicy pitches against Australia'
22553315
Ice Cricket: Legends play T20 in the Alps
22584758
Dhoni, Kohli and quirky on-field  chatter
```

Comment: what does json.dumps() do?

Comment: Just print the output of variable `d` you will get the answer as `OrderedDict` not as dict in json format, so just converted to plain json using `json.dumps`

Comment: Yeah but the output dstring is a string, I can't render this on the template , I get jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'items' error

Comment: can I fix this? @amazingthingsaround

Comment: @steve yes.. just moment .. let me try t.

Comment: can I strip that 'u' tag?, it won't be a problem anyhow

Comment: @steve try it using with `jinja` ... I think you are using it in `Django` framework. Try using it you won't get error.

Comment: That's right I'm using jinja 2 with Flask framework but the problem still persists {% for title, link in dstring.items() %}, I get the same error even the dstring is not string,

Comment: You don't have to use `dString` variable. Just a minute let me change the variable for you. This time you have to use `string_json`. check the edit.

Comment: I tried by changing variable also but I got same error

Comment: I'm able to render on the template but value get randomly assigned to some video, even key, value for that loop is same key value get changed, see this image https://imgur.com/a/5hXgQ, check the video embedded id and other id printed next to video they both are different but embedded id is randomly assigned other two values are correct

Comment: @steve now try the edited answer.  Now everything will be proper. I got the mistake now you can try.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing as this imgur.com/a/5hXgQ, take a look here for complete code and o/p  https://codeshare.io/a3xrdD

Comment: I guess that was your question which I have already answered. It seems to be a different question. And what you have asked it the concatenation or joining two lists in order, which I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should never rely on order of elements when using the default `dict` even if it happens to match some expectation. There is a dedicated dictionary implementation that keeps the order of insertion, starting from 2.7:

```
class collections.OrderedDict([items])
```

> Return an instance of a dict subclass, supporting the usual dict methods. An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and reinserting it will move it to the end.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()

d["1"] = 1
d["5"] = 5
d["2"] = 2
print(d) #OrderedDict([('1', 1), ('5', 5), ('2', 2)])

new_d = dict(d)

print(d) #{'1': 1, '5': 5, '2': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since lists are an ordered collection, this works for me:

```
mydict = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```